# Section symbol showing up in section headings and toc

Tags: document-classes, books

I jumped in to editing a book document class and we want to now remove the section symbols from the toc and the section titles.  I cannot figure out why they are there in the first place.  Regardless, how can they be removed?

I think the following are relevant.

From the style file:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textsection\thechapter\alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection(\roman{subsection})}
```

Packages used:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{url}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textsection\thechapter\alph{section}}` puts a section mark (`\textsection`) in front of the number

Comment: Perfect!  It was hard to dig out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textsection\thechapter\alph{section}}
```

puts a section mark (`\textsection`) in front of the number